# Altium Designer - Place component with actual stand-off height over other components

Tags: altium

Recently I created a new component with the following footprint:

[image: Footprint]

And the following 3D body:

[image: 3dBody]

Since the component (Programmer Board) has got plenty of space underneath it, I'd like to place other components there. Somehow Altium does not allow it  or rather moves other components out of the way if I try to push the Programmer Board over them and I can't figure out why.

I tried to fix it with the help of design rules, which didn't work at all (Component Clearence 0mil). I also made sure, that there is no keep out area on the footprint:

[image]

I'd be very glad if someone could help me with this one.

Comment: You already made the through hole pads, just change the one component to 4 headers and you’re done. I can imagine Altium doesn’t like this, because it’s not unlikely some smd components could make contact with the headers on that sister pcb. But if you insist, maybe you could define a room around that sister pcb and define looser design rules specifically for that area.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I really would like to have it as a component. Unfortunately Design rules didn't help me, as a already mentioned. I think it must have something to do with de footprint.